# Convert styled letter to regular letter in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I convert styled letter to regular letter in NodeJs?
For example, if user input   as first name I want to save unstyled first name (Da Yeon) into the database instead of  .

Comment: FYI, the Unicode for those characters are `` &#120383; `` &#120406; `` &#120404; `` &#120410; `` &#120420; `` &#120419;

Comment: Please be careful in implementing this.  For example, in Swedish `Å` is not just a stylized `A`, or even an `A` with a diacritical mark.  it's a completely different letter.